# Docker - run provisioning script in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, nexus3

This is I want to achieve - please, don't ask me why :)

I want to run container with two scripts (using Dockerfile): default one + additional script which will execute some operations on container after 1 minute.

**EDIT:**
This is service container so it should be working after executing additional script.

What will be the best way to do that?

Comment: Why dont you add a sleep after you have executed the first part  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a single `ENTRYPOINT` script which combines the two scripts, with a `sleep` between them. For example:

`entrypoint.sh`

```
<execute steps from default script>
sleep 1m
<execute steps from additional script>
```

And define this as the last step in the `Dockerfile`:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: This will be service container, so ENTRYPOINT will make it exit after executing script :) - see EDIT. What can we do in this situation?

Comment: Is there a process within the container that you are running as a service - for example nginx? In this case, you can run this from `ENTRYPOINT` and it will not exit. If there are no processes (not reccomended), you can always run `tail -f /dev/null` in the last line of your `ENTRYPOINT` to keep the container running.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I have this problem - my ENTRYPOINT script contains following lines:

1) ${SONATYPE_DIR}/start-nexus-repository-manager.sh
2) curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET  'http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/repositories'
3) touch ./file

First - it is default script running nexus repository manager, two others are additional scripts. Logs are ending with: "Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.13.0-01" so after if I should expect logged result from curl / created file?

Comment: Ideally there should only be one process running in a container. If you want to run additional scripts it's probably best to run them in a separate container and coordinate them using docker compose.